# Getting 302 found error while sending huge data in POST Angular 4code

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, http, post

I'm trying to save data of about 1.5MB (about 6000 objects in an array) using a **POST** call in my angular 4 app using the below method.

```
  saveWeatherData(data: any): Promise<any[]> {
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        const url = this.baseUrl + '/save';
        return this.http.post(url, data, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

While saving this huge records I'm gettting error response as **302 Found**

**Details:**

> {   "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
>       "type": "microTask",
>       "state": "notScheduled",
>       "source": "Promise.then",
>       "zone": "angular",
>       "cancelFn": null,
>       "runCount": 0   } }

While the same is not happening while sending data less that 1 MB(about 2000-3000 records).I'm getting response as 200 Ok.

Do let me know where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 302 is not an error response.

Comment: are you using Nginx in backend?

Comment: **302 Found** is a redirect code. Observe the `Location` field of the response headers. Also, watch your server code for anything written over there. Your server may be redirecting to a different location when the size is larger.